# Traversing JSON to buid a parent child output with Javascript

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, tree-traversal

I have to traverse the below input JSON to build a parent child relation as in the sample JSON.

Logic, the element which has immediate_parent_id of -1 that becomes a root node. Than root node immediate_dependents are it's child. Now I have to pick up the each dependent of immediate_dependents and look for matching node_id and that particular elements immediate_dependents become its child. Like this I have to traverse till the nth Level of JSON. What's the optimal way of achieving this. I don't want to use jQuery. Looking out to be solved using javascript.

Input JSON

```
[
   {
      "node_id":1,
      "token":"Google",
      "posTag":"NNP",
      "depLabel":"compound",
      "node_role":{

      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":2,
         "name":"News"
      },
      "entity_tag":{
         "originalTag":"B-ORG",
         "prefix":"B",
         "position":"begin",
         "mainCategory":"ORG",
         "entityDescription":"Organization",
         "examples":"Government Agency, Broadcaster, Company, Educational Institution, Employers Organization, Non-Profit Organization, Samba School, Sports League, Sports Team, Website"
      },
      "siblings":[

      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         2,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":2,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":2,
      "token":"News",
      "posTag":"NNP",
      "depLabel":"nsubj",
      "node_role":{
         "parent_verb_id":3,
         "grandparent_verb_id":3,
         "role":"topic"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"be.01",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":3,
         "name":"is"
      },
      "entity_tag":{
         "originalTag":"L-ORG",
         "prefix":"L",
         "position":"last",
         "mainCategory":"ORG",
         "entityDescription":"Organization",
         "examples":"Government Agency, Broadcaster, Company, Educational Institution, Employers Organization, Non-Profit Organization, Samba School, Sports League, Sports Team, Website"
      },
      "siblings":[
         6,
         12
      ],
      "dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":1,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         }
      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":1,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         }
      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":3,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":3,
      "token":"is",
      "posTag":"VBZ",
      "depLabel":"root",
      "node_role":{
         "parent_verb_id":3
      },
      "verb_info":[
         {
            "is_verb":true,
            "nodeID":3,
            "negation":null,
            "lemma":"be",
            "id":"be-109-1-1",
            "pbID":"be.01",
            "meaningUsage":"copula",
            "verb_synonyms":[
               "be",
               "prove",
               "appear",
               "seem"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":-1,
         "name":null
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[

      ],
      "dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":2,
            "name":"News",
            "depLabel":"nsubj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":1,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         },
         {
            "dependent":6,
            "name":"aggregator",
            "depLabel":"attr"
         },
         {
            "dependent":4,
            "name":"a",
            "depLabel":"det"
         },
         {
            "dependent":5,
            "name":"news",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         },
         {
            "dependent":7,
            "name":"and",
            "depLabel":"cc"
         },
         {
            "dependent":8,
            "name":"app",
            "depLabel":"conj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":9,
            "name":"developed",
            "depLabel":"acl"
         },
         {
            "dependent":10,
            "name":"by",
            "depLabel":"agent"
         },
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":12,
            "name":".",
            "depLabel":"punct"
         }
      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[

      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":2,
            "name":"News",
            "depLabel":"nsubj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":6,
            "name":"aggregator",
            "depLabel":"attr"
         },
         {
            "dependent":12,
            "name":".",
            "depLabel":"punct"
         }
      ],
      "isRoot":true,
      "immediate_parent_id":-1,
      "parentVerbID":-1
   },
   {
      "node_id":4,
      "token":"a",
      "posTag":"DT",
      "depLabel":"det",
      "node_role":{
         "role":"comment"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":6,
         "name":"aggregator"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         5,
         7,
         8,
         9
      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":6,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":5,
      "token":"news",
      "posTag":"NN",
      "depLabel":"compound",
      "node_role":{
         "role":"comment"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":6,
         "name":"aggregator"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         4,
         7,
         8,
         9
      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":6,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":6,
      "token":"aggregator",
      "posTag":"NN",
      "depLabel":"attr",
      "node_role":{
         "parent_verb_id":3
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"be.01",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":3,
         "name":"is"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         2,
         12
      ],
      "dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":4,
            "name":"a",
            "depLabel":"det"
         },
         {
            "dependent":5,
            "name":"news",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         },
         {
            "dependent":7,
            "name":"and",
            "depLabel":"cc"
         },
         {
            "dependent":8,
            "name":"app",
            "depLabel":"conj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":9,
            "name":"developed",
            "depLabel":"acl"
         },
         {
            "dependent":10,
            "name":"by",
            "depLabel":"agent"
         },
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":4,
            "name":"a",
            "depLabel":"det"
         },
         {
            "dependent":5,
            "name":"news",
            "depLabel":"compound"
         },
         {
            "dependent":7,
            "name":"and",
            "depLabel":"cc"
         },
         {
            "dependent":8,
            "name":"app",
            "depLabel":"conj"
         },
         {
            "dependent":9,
            "name":"developed",
            "depLabel":"acl"
         }
      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":3,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":7,
      "token":"and",
      "posTag":"CC",
      "depLabel":"cc",
      "node_role":{
         "role":"comment"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":6,
         "name":"aggregator"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         4,
         5,
         8,
         9
      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":6,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":8,
      "token":"app",
      "posTag":"NN",
      "depLabel":"conj",
      "node_role":{
         "role":"comment"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":6,
         "name":"aggregator"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         4,
         5,
         7,
         9
      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":6,
      "parentVerbID":3
   },
   {
      "node_id":9,
      "token":"developed",
      "posTag":"VBN",
      "depLabel":"acl",
      "node_role":{
         "parent_verb_id":9,
         "role":"comment"
      },
      "verb_info":[
         {
            "is_verb":true,
            "nodeID":9,
            "negation":null,
            "lemma":"develop",
            "id":"develop-26.1",
            "pbID":"develop.02",
            "meaningUsage":"create",
            "verb_synonyms":[
               "sculpt",
               "cut",
               "remake",
               "shape",
               "make",
               "carve",
               "build"
            ]
         }
      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":6,
         "name":"aggregator"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[
         4,
         5,
         7,
         8
      ],
      "dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":10,
            "name":"by",
            "depLabel":"agent"
         },
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":10,
            "name":"by",
            "depLabel":"agent"
         }
      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":6,
      "parentVerbID":-1
   },
   {
      "node_id":10,
      "token":"by",
      "posTag":"IN",
      "depLabel":"agent",
      "node_role":{
         "parent_verb_id":9,
         "grandparent_verb_id":9,
         "role":"creator"
      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"develop.02",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":9,
         "name":"developed"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[

      ],
      "dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         9,
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[
         {
            "dependent":11,
            "name":"Google",
            "depLabel":"pobj"
         }
      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":9,
      "parentVerbID":9
   },
   {
      "node_id":11,
      "token":"Google",
      "posTag":"NNP",
      "depLabel":"pobj",
      "node_role":{

      },
      "verb_info":[

      ],
      "action_verb_roleset":"",
      "parent_node":{
         "parent_node":10,
         "name":"by"
      },
      "entity_tag":null,
      "siblings":[

      ],
      "dependents":[

      ],
      "pobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "dobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "nobj_dependents":[

      ],
      "parents":[
         10,
         9,
         6,
         3
      ],
      "immediate_dependents":[

      ],
      "isRoot":false,
      "immediate_parent_id":10,
      "parentVerbID":9
   }
]
```

Sample JSON Output(to render the d3 tree)

```
   {  
   "name":"is",
   "children":[  
      {  
         "name":"news",
         "children":[  
            {  
               "name":"Google",
               "children":[  

               ]
            },
            {  
               "name":"aggregator",
               "children":[  
                  {  
                     "name":"a",
                     "children":[  

                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"news",
                     "children":[  

                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"app",
                     "children":[  

                     ]
                  },
                  {  
                     "name":"developed",
                     "children":[  
                        {  
                           "name":"by"
                        }
                     ]
                  }
               ]
            },
            {  
               "name":".",
               "children":[  

               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: please add what relations has the first data to the second data structure.

Comment: @NinaScholz relations are dependent value and node_id value

Comment: ok, how do you get from `name = 'a'` to `name = 'flare'`, for example? maybe you add some code to illustrate the wanted outcome.

Comment: @NinaScholz no that's a sample JSON to explain the expected output. the data in it will be replaced by the original one

Comment: please add a corresponding output to the given input.

Comment: @NinaScholz Sorry for that edited the question. Hope this helps. We have to traverse all the nodes

Comment: you still miss the code, you tried.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/182005/discussion-between-vijaym-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take an iterative approach by storing all know information, lije parent and children in an object and get then obly the root children.

```js
var data = [{ node_id: 1, token: "Google", parent_node: { parent_node: 2, name: "News" } }, { node_id: 2, token: "News", parent_node: { parent_node: 3, name: "is" } }, { node_id: 3, token: "is", parent_node: { parent_node: -1, name: null } }, { node_id: 4, token: "a", parent_node: { parent_node: 6, name: "aggregator" } }, { node_id: 5, token: "news", parent_node: { parent_node: 6, name: "aggregator" } }, { node_id: 6, token: "aggregator", parent_node: { parent_node: 3, name: "is" } }, { node_id: 7, token: "and", parent_node: { parent_node: 6, name: "aggregator" } }, { node_id: 8, token: "app", parent_node: { parent_node: 6, name: "aggregator" } }, { node_id: 9, token: "developed", parent_node: { parent_node: 6, name: "aggregator" } }, { node_id: 10, token: "by", parent_node: { parent_node: 9, name: "developed" } }, { node_id: 11, token: "Google", parent_node: { parent_node: 10, name: "by" } }],
    tree = function (data, root) {
        var o = {};
        data.forEach(function ({ node_id: id, token: name, parent_node: { parent_node: parent } }) {
            var temp = { name };
            if (o[id] && o[id].children) {
                temp.children = o[id].children;
            }
            o[id] = temp;
            o[parent] = o[parent] || {};
            o[parent].children = o[parent].children || [];
            o[parent].children.push(temp);

        });
        return o[root].children;
    }(data, -1);

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```